# How to create multiple subsets from dataframe with for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I have a loop x creating subset question want to be solved:

So I have a dataframe called df with more than 300 columns.

I want to create subset df_21 with df col1~20+col21 and subset df_22 with df col1~20+col22, same condition for the remaining 200+ subsets.

```
df_21=df.iloc[:,:21]  #I know this code can only be used for df_21
```

So each subset will have 21 columns.

Then I want to create a new col for each subset called 'newcol' with the value from the name of column 21 in that subset. (so it would be df.col 21 for df_21 and df.col 22 for df_22 actually)

```
colname= ''.join(list(df_21[[20]]))  #I bring out the name of col21 as a list first and then convert it to string by command ''.join

df_21['newcol'] = np.where(df_21[[20]] == "Y", colname[7:],"")
```

↑ Then I set the condition for that newcol (column 22): when the value in column 21=="Y", paste the name of column21 into the corresponding cell of newcol but excluding the first 8 characters in the name of column21

I want to do the above steps for 200+ columns after column 20 so there would be 200+ subsets (eg. df_21 ~ df_250)
I tried to do a loop to solve it but I failed.

If you have any better solutions please let me know!
Thank you!